# nodogsplash Error: No such file or directory

Tags: openwrt

After I install & run `ndscl status` then error:

```
ndsctl: nodogsplash probably not started (Error: No such file or directory)
```

I tried reinstalling but still got this error. Did Anybody meet this error?
Tks.

Comment: did you manage to fix your issue ? I got the same problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the option enable flag to 1 in the /etc/config/nodogsplash file.

Comment: duh! Thanks a lot. FYI I've edited https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/wireless.hotspot.nodogsplash#installation to add this.